# xPage launched in Notes Client 853 FP5 on win7 displayed as html web pages, no error though

Tags: xpages

The xPage app was developed and compiled using 851 designer by someone else...
Were suppose to be used inside Notes Client.

Only two of my users when they open the xpage app in the Notes Client 853FP5 standard config on win7 everything displays and no error however it wasn't in xpage UI, instead it looks like some domino view being loaded in a web browser. but all xpage buttons and links are working and displayed. Just the not xpage UI.

If I try to load the app in a web browser, all seems to load fine.

Any ideas? as no other user has got  the same issue. If it is an issue with win7, then they are all on win7 though, Or any suggestions in terms of where to start from to debug this issue?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You mention that it's not the "xpage UI" but that "xpage buttons and links are working". It sounds like a caching issue for the CSS files. Try the keyboard shortcut Ctrl-Shift-Delete to clear the local cache.

[image]

Source: http://ypastov.blogspot.dk/2013/08/xpinc-clearing-cache.html

Comment: Tried, all the same though.

Comment: Plus it wasn't like I have updated anything on the xpage app.

Comment: The reason I say it looks like web page instead of xpage is you know the old way of loading a domino view in the web client directly, domino automatically gives you previous and next links on the top of the view... Dare I say it seems to be almost like those two users have access issue with the css files the xpage app is using... a total guess. but then both of them are set as Edit in the DB ACL

Comment: But you also say that the xpages buttons and links are working. On the same page?